# VBA to filter cut and paste

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to macros and VBA in general. Just trying to automate some filtering that would save me a ton of time. I have been trying to work on a macro within excel to select data, filter on certain criteria (below i have it on one filter for ease) cut, and then paste to a new sheet. I want it to also delete the empty rows from which I cut from. The code below only copies and does not delete.

```
Sub filtertest()
Dim LastRow As Long

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

'Find the last row
LastRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

'Select Table
Range("A1:K" & LastRow).Select

'Filter table
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="51192"

'Copy/Paste
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Turn off autofilter
Selection.Autofilter

End Sub
```

I also tried to mesh some other code together for this to combine it all. However I keep getting errors about an object. Not sure if it is because of the "sub button_click()" or what as I said I am new to this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns(1).AutoFilter 1, "51192"
With Range("a1", Range("i" & Rows.Count).End(3))
    .Copy FalsePositives.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Offset(1)
    .EntireRow.Delete
End With
Columns(1).AutoFilter
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: you did not declare `FalsePositives` as a worksheet.

Comment: When I 'Dim FalsePositives As Worksheet' in the beginning I get a run time error 91 object variable or with block variable not set.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the values then return and delete the originals, skipping the header.

```
Sub filtertest()
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")

        'Find the last row
        LastRow = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

        'Filter table
        .Range("A1:K" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="51192"


        'Copy/Paste
        .Range("A1:K" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        'remove originals
        .Range("A1:K" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete

        'Turn off autofilter
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfect. Now if I wanted to filter on more than one criteria I would just add another .Range Row? The criteria would be in the same field as well. So when I cut and paste the new criteria I want it to start on the next blank row in sheet2 so it does not overlap the data that was previously put on there.

Comment: No, you would add a Criteria2 to the .AutoFilter with xlAnd or xlOr. Record yourself performing this to get the syntax.